# unfortunately flutter application has stopped in my device

Tags: flutter

I am testing my flutter application in the low version Samsung 4.4.1 it works correctly before i add fire base to my project but it is not working after that,

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G355H in debug mode...

Initializing gradle...

Resolving dependencies...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.

Application finished.
```

Comment: Looks a bit thin to me, I doubt anyone will be able to help you with this little detail. Maybe take a look at what Logcat is telling you when the app closes?

Comment: not displaying any thing ,i think it a version issue or something it works on other devices

Comment: Logcat is not showing any error,the application doesn't have any error on the latest versions ,it appears only on 4.4.1 mobile device ,if you have any idea that help ?julien-lachal

Comment: Please don't add additional details as comments. Update your question.

Comment: @john how you solved it?